# How to add JWT header on fullcalendar v5 events URL

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am trying to get fullcalendar working with my API, which needs a token passed for authentication, but I am not familiar with Angular or Typescript enough to figure out what I need to do to complete what I have already, so my current implementation is incomplete.  I just don't know what I need to do to complete it.

In older versions, you were able to add a header through eventSources, but at least in fullcalendar v5, that no longer works.  From what I understand, I need to pass a function to `events` in order to intercept the call and modify the header with the token.  I have an injectable for HttpClient that automatically adds the token to the header of HttpClient calls, but I'm not sure what the `event` parameter expects to be returned from the function, or how to convert the response to be recognized by it.

I have this in my events.service.ts:

```js
public getEvents(start: string, end: string){
    let params = new HttpParams().set("start", start).set("end", end)
    return this.httpClient.get<EventModel[]>(environment.scheduleUrl + 'api/events/', {params: params});
  }
```

This is called through a method I am keeping in my component for now:

```js
handleGetEvents(info) {
    let response = this.eventsService.getEvents(info.startStr, info.endStr);
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }
```

The `events` parameter calls that last method with this:

```js
events: this.handleGetEvents.bind(this),
```

This does retrieve the events from the server, and I can see them in the console, but unlike when I remove authentication checks and just use the url, such as `events: environment.scheduleUrl + 'api/events/,`, it doesn't populate the events to the calendar.  I assume that is because it is not typed correctly, but I'm not sure, and I'm not sure how to convert the results to a type that can be recognized.

Comment: AFAIK fullcalendar v5 doesn't able us to add HTTP headers on the fly. The solution would be to use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. However there is a feature request here https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4627.

Comment: Yeah, I found that stuff already, which is why I was trying to do it as a function, but I'm not sure how the data is supposed to be returned, or really how to convert an observable to whatever data type it is looking to be returned.

Comment: You must call the successCallback with an array of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Comment: And as I said, I don't know how to do that.  I created a model, which is the `EventModel`, which I assume is what I need to do, but I'm not sure how to map the response to the model, so I can pass it off to successCallback.  It keeps complaining that it needs to be of the type `EventInput[]`, or that the variable I do pass is missing a bunch of properties.

Comment: `Argument of type 'Observable<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventInput[]'.
      Type 'Observable<string>' is missing the following properties from type 'EventInput[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.`

Comment: Oh now I understand. What version of fullcalendar are you using ? If using fullcalendar v5, You can use the callback DatesSet to fetch the events according to a given date range. That's how I do in my current project.

Comment: I'm using v5.  I already have the dates being passed to my API, which returns the events from the appropriate date range.  The problem I am having is between receiving the events from the API and handing them off to fullcalendar.  Even using the successCallback, I get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) for Fullcalendar v5, the `events` option supports function that may return a Promise-like object. You already have an Observable to fetch your events and you now need to convert it to a Promise. To convert an Observable to a Promise, you can use the `toPromise` method.

```
export class AppComponent {
  public calendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    events: this.fetchEvents.bind(this)
  };

  constructor(private events: EventsService) {}

  public fetchEvents(dateInfo) {
    return this.events.get(dateInfo.start, dateInfo.end).toPromise();
  }
}
```

`EventsService` consists of:

```
@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
  constructor() {}

  /** Return the events for the given span. */
  get(start: string, end: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return of([]); // Remove this and do the query to your backend service with the JWT header
  }
}
```

See a live demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-new-nciowx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: That addressed exactly what I needed to know.